# Setting "clipboard to" verses system events command+C

Tags: applescript, applescript-numbers

Using AppleScript to manipulate Numbers to help organize youth wrestling tournaments:

The relevant portion of my script looks like this:

```
    -- SELECT THE ROWS
    tell document 1
        tell active sheet
            tell table 1
                set WeightClassRows to ¬
                    ((name of first cell of row "3") & ":" & (name of last cell of row EndWeightClass))
                set the selection range to range WeightClassRows
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
```

So far, it works. Once I have certain rows selected, I need to copy the information and paste it elsewhere. This works:

```
    -- COPY THE INFORMATION 

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "c" using {command down}
    end tell

    ...

    -- PASTE THE INFORMATION SOMEWHERE ELSE

    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "v" using {command down, option down, shift down}
    end tell
```

But I would prefer to use the clipboard to copy the information rather than system events. However, I can't figure it out despite searching and trying a number of things, such as:

```
    set the clipboard to WeightClassRows   

    set the clipboard to range WeightClassRows

    set the clipboard to content of WeightClassRows

    set the clipboard to content of selection range
```

But none of these (or similar things) work. Either it returns the cell reference ("B3:J9"), nothing at all, or returns an error saying something like "Can't get content of B3:J9"

Any ideas on how to use the clipboard rather than system events to copy the information once it is selected?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term `content` in commonly-used AppleScript terminology, although I don't use _Numbers_, so it may be specific to that.  But, most often, `contents` is used to evaluate an AppleScript object.  Regarding the clipboard, one of the troubles is that AppleScript uses a different, older API to manipulate the clipboard versus the one used when triggering `cmd-V`. To get some insight, perform a copy with _System Events_, then in _Script Editor_, run the command `return the clipboard info` to see what sort of data gets put on there (also: `return the clipboard as record`).